# About sequences of positive integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

Prove there is no sequence of positive integers $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ so that:
$$
x_{n+2} = x_{n+1} + x_{x_n} \quad \forall n\ge1 
$$

I think the idea is to find two different values for the same index.

Comment: Good idea to start with.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Erick Wong Not much, still thinking of it

Comment: You have posted a lot of contest math questions lately. I think it would be better, if you included the source as well.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Not so easy to include the source, all the problems I posted here are from local contests, not posted on internet (or so I think). As about me, it happens to have some free time, so I'm trying to have some fun with math. Therefore I'm not dying to see my problems solved.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If there was such a sequence, apart from possibly the first term, it would be strictly increasing. We'd have

\begin{align}
x_3 &= x_2 + x_{x_1} \geqslant 1 + 1 = 2\\
x_4 &= x_3 + x_{x_2} \geqslant 2 + 1 = 3\\
x_5 &= x_4 + x_{x_3} \geqslant 3 + 1 = 4\\
x_6 &= x_5 + x_{x_4} \geqslant 4 + x_3 \geqslant 6\\
x_7 &= x_6 + x_{x_5} \geqslant 6 + x_4 \geqslant 9,
\end{align}

and thus $x_k \geqslant k + 2$ for all $k \geqslant 7$. But then we'd have

$$x_{n+2} = x_{n+1} + x_{x_n} > x_{x_n} \geqslant x_{n+2}$$

for $n \geqslant 7$. Which of course is impossible.

Comment: Why do you use $\geqslant$ instead of $\ge$?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Because I find it looks (much) better.

Comment: Beautiful proof!